# How to get table row above (or before) my current row in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a variable which holds a table row.

How would I get the row right before it using javascript/jquery?

Comment: Are you talking about a table row? Need a little more detail here.

Comment: Are both rows inside the same table section element (TBODY for instance)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This:

```
var prevRow = row.previousElementSibling;
```

or

```
var prevRow = $( row ).prev()[0];
```

(`[0]` is used to "unwrap the jQuery object", to get the DOM reference to that row. If you want to perform jQuery methods on that row, you can just leave it inside, like `$( row ).prev().addClass( '...' );` and in that case you don't need a new variable.)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the two rows are siblings (not contained in separate `tbody` or `thead` elements):

```
$curRow = $(this); // or however you're getting the current `tr`.
$curRow.prev('tr');
```

Should get you the previous row.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to do something like so:

`$("#cellID").parent().prev()`

Answer (score 1):

Your input is not sufficient but if i understand correctly here is the code for your requirement..

```
If your Variable contains table row id  then $('#yourVariableName').prev('tr')[0] will work.
If your Variable contains table row Class  then $('.yourVariableName').prev('tr')[0] will work.
If your Variable contains table row index  then $(' table tr').eq(varValue).prev('tr')[0] will work.
```

But please specify what your variable will contain.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to get the input value from the td in the tr above the current one:

```
$('#id').prev().children('td').children(':text').val();
```